# Describe type of seqeunces that satisfy $(\exists \varepsilon > 0)(\forall n_\varepsilon)(\forall n > n_\varepsilon) : |x_n - a| < \varepsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I need to describe type of seqeunces that satisfy the condition below and provide an example.

$$(\exists \varepsilon > 0) (\forall n_\varepsilon)
    (\forall n > n_\varepsilon) : |x_n - a| < \varepsilon $$

I have 2 main questions

1. Doesn't $(\exists \varepsilon > 0)$ mean that epslion can be infinitely large, so any sequence can satisfy condition above?
2. What exatly means $\forall n_\varepsilon$. I always thought of $n_\varepsilon$ as some value that equals to $f(\varepsilon)$. "All" means there can multiple values, so formula for n looks like $n_\varepsilon > f(\varepsilon), n_\varepsilon \in N$ (just an example) ?

Comment: These are just **bounded** sequences.

Comment: @geetha290krm could you elaborate, please? What if we have seqence $\{x: x = n\}_{n=1}^{n \to \infty}$ which is not bounded above. Let $a = 1$, then exists epsilon $\varepsilon = |x_n - a| +1 =| n - 1 | + 1$.  Am i gettings something wrong here?

Comment: $\epsilon$ cannot depend on $n$.

Comment: Now I get it, thanks a lot.

Comment: 1. Yes. $\epsilon$ can be infinitely large. 2. just make $n_\epsilon = 1$